# Knowledge structure to matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a knowledge structure, e.g.  `={{∅},{a},{b},{bc},{abd},{abcd},{abcde}}` and want it displayed as a matrix. How can I do that in R? Function `blim()` in package `pks` *takes* a matrix, which requires that I *have* one.

---

Falmagne, J.-C., Koppen, M., Villano, M., Doignon, J.-P., & Johannesen, L. (1990). Introduction to knowledge spaces: How to build, test and search them. *Psychological Review, 97*, 201224. doi:[10.1037/0033-295X.97.2.201](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/0033-295X.97.2.201)

Comment: This question would seem to require more knowledge of "knowledge structures" than general R programming.

Comment: The documentation for package pks at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pks/pks.pdf is not terribly clear to me about what this matrix should look like, but I am not a specialist in this area.  I do note that the very next entry in the docs give a data library data(chess) for examples of knowledge structures given in a paper analyzing chess. So, if you can't contact the author or others who use this particular software, possibly you could read the chess paper that is cited and look at the data structures provided.

Comment: OP, I don't know what 'knowledge structure' is and am guessing that's not common knowledge - if you explain what matrix you expect to get out of that string that would increase your chances of getting an answer significantly

Comment: @Paul I wasn't sure if I should post this in stats.SE or here. Please move the question, if you feel it belongs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An appropriate example of such a matrix or

> a state-by-problem indicator matrix representing the knowledge
>   structure. An element is one if the problem is contained in the state,
>   and else zero

could be the one from the `blim` documentation:

```
data(DoignonFalmagne7)
DoignonFalmagne7$K
      a b c d e
00000 0 0 0 0 0
10000 1 0 0 0 0
01000 0 1 0 0 0
11000 1 1 0 0 0
11100 1 1 1 0 0
11010 1 1 0 1 0
11110 1 1 1 1 0
11101 1 1 1 0 1
11111 1 1 1 1 1
```

Assuming that knowledge structure is supplied as a character vector and the empty set corresponds to `""` one could proceed as follows:

```
kStruct <- c("", "a", "b", "bc", "abd", "abcd", "abcde")
ul <- strsplit(kStruct, "")
cn <- unique(unlist(ul))
K <- t(sapply(ul, function(x) cn %in% x) * 1)
dimnames(K) <- list(apply(K, 1, paste, collapse = ""), cn)
K
      a b c d e
00000 0 0 0 0 0
10000 1 0 0 0 0
01000 0 1 0 0 0
01100 0 1 1 0 0
11010 1 1 0 1 0
11110 1 1 1 1 0
11111 1 1 1 1 1
```

Alternatively:

```
cn <- unique(unlist(strsplit(kStruct, "")))
K <- sapply(cn, grepl, kStruct) * 1
rownames(K) <- apply(K, 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

Also note that, as I can see, the names of rows of columns are not necessary for `blim`.